# Leaflet switch layer control and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, leaflet

I'm currently developing a website using Leaflet to display statistics data.

My sources are written in geoJSON and settled in a JavaScript array. 
Basically I want to export my render as PDF but my map contains a layer switcher.

Here is an example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/htFHBOm.png]

I use PhantomJS for the export but it only draws my first layer. When I switch my layers, colors of counties are changing but not in my PDF file.

My source file is like that:

[image]

I use json-tags ("EDS", "MCO", etc...) called like in the layer switcher to detect values and color counties with a proper legend.

You have the getColor function:

```
function getColor_MCO(d) {
    return d > 38 ? '#800026' :
           d > 33  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 27  ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 21   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 14   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#000';
}
```

The styling function:

```
function style_MCO(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '5',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: getColor_MCO(feature.properties.MCO)
    };
}
```

This is the way I initialize the switch layer option:

```
var MCO = L.geoJson(toulonData, {
    style: style_MCO,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
        layer.bindPopup("<b>Nom de la region : </b> " + feature.properties.Name +
            "<br><b>Taux d'attractivite (en %) : </b>" + feature.properties.MCO
            ,popupOptions);
            //highlight
    function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
});

info1.update(layer.feature.properties);
```

And finally, this is how the switch layer option works:

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (eventLayer) {
    if (eventLayer.name === 'EDS') {
        map.removeControl(currentLegend);
        currentLegend = legend_EDS;
        legend_EDS.addTo(map);
        map.removeControl(currentInfo);
        currentInfo=info0;
        info0.addTo(map);
    }
    else if (eventLayer.name === 'MCO') {
        map.removeControl(currentLegend);
        currentLegend = legend_MCO;
        legend_MCO.addTo(map);
         map.removeControl(currentInfo);
        currentInfo=info1;
        info1.addTo(map);
    }
    else if ... (same for the others)
```